# sharepoint 2010 search IE vs FF

Tags: search

When I search for `créer`:

```
IE: http://172.23.113.79/Recherche/_layouts/SubNew.aspx?ATName=OSS.Search&Title=Rechercher%C2%A0%3A%20cr%C3%A9er%2A&Source=http%3A%2F%2F172%2E23%2E113%2E79%2Frecherche%2Fpages%2FResults%2Easpx%3Fk%3Dcr%C3%83%C2%A9er%2A

FF: http://172.23.113.79/Recherche/_layouts/SubNew.aspx?ATName=OSS.Search&Title=Rechercher%C2%A0%3A%20cr%C3%A9er*&Source=http%3A%2F%2F172.23.113.79%2Frecherche%2Fpages%2FResults.aspx%3Fk%3Dcr%C3%A9er*
```

Can you see the difference?

How strange is that?

How can i fix that?

So it doesn't search with strange characters like: `crÃ©er`

Comment: Is this effecting the search results, or is this a purely an aesthetic preference for the URLs to be the same?

Answer (score 1):

IE encodes more than FF. Try pasting this url into address bar of IE and FF:
http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Créer

Here are some examples of encoded characters:

%2A
*

%2E
.

So if the search results are the same, there is nothing to worry about.